# GUI freezing when shutil copy files

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar, freeze, ttk

```
def creabackuno():
  startbar()
  messagebox.showinfo( "Wait..","I am creating the backup, please wait...")
  try:
      copytree(path,r"backup\dirbackup1\.minecraft")
      messagebox.showinfo( "OK!","Backup (1) created!")
      stopbar()
  except OSError as exc:
      messagebox.showerror( "Nope!","There is already a backup to restore")
      stopbar()
```

I have a problem with a progressbar:

The startbar() start the progressbar on the graphic interface, but when start shutil(copytree(path,r"backup\dirbackup1.minecraft")) the interface freezing and the progressbar stop until it finished.
thanks

i'm using python 3.3

sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 2):

What does the progress bar show?  If you are trying to show the percent of the file copied then you have to get the total length/bytes of the file first and then update periodically with the number of bytes copied.  That would require using "after" to check the size of the copy-to file every so many milliseconds (I think as I am just guessing here, but search first as there has to be someone who has already done something like this.)  This is the first link that I found https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2010-December/002613.html  It may be more than you want but should help.

Answer (score 1):

`copytree` is a synchronous function, so all code execution will stop until it's done. Although tkinter is sad not to be thread-safe I recommend that you put that command in another thread:

```
from thread import start_new_thread as snt
#from _thread import start_new_thread as snt for python 3

def copy(onError,onEnd):
    try: copytree(path,r"backup\dirbackup1\.minecraft")
    except: 
       onError()
       return
    onEnd()

def onEnd():
    messagebox.showinfo( "OK!","Backup (1) created!")
    stopbar()

def onError():
      messagebox.showerror( "Nope!","There is already a backup to restore")
      stopbar()

#then call with

snt(copy,(onError,onEnd))
```

Execs onError if it fails and onEnd on success.

Comment: he said, he uses python 3, and `thread` module in python3 is `_thread`

Comment: You have other solution? this is very difficult to implemented in my code.

Answer (score 0):

use `self.Frame.update_idletasks()` after every `self.pgBar.step(x)` statement,where 'x' stands for the value by which progressbar's value increases

Comment: the progress bar run in indeterminate mode, but when shutil start to copy file the interface freezing